# SQL Server : convert columns to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have following input in SQL Server

[image: Input of data]

I need to convert in the following output

[image: Output needs to be same as shown in this immage 2]

Is it possible in SQL Server? If yes please provide the solution asap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate and/or multi account: [Sql Convert columns to rows and rows to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404550/sql-convert-columns-to-rows-and-rows-to-columns)

Comment: Have you considered a self join?

Comment: SO isn't a "write my code for me" service, and certainly **not** a "write my code for me **ASAP**" service. Please post what have you tried

Comment: `PIVOT` for the win.

Comment: Same class as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404550/convert-columns-to-rows-and-rows-to-columns?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
  SELECT 
  x.col2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN x.col1 = 48 THEN x.col3 END) AS [48],
  MAX(CASE WHEN x.col1 = 49 THEN x.col3 END) AS [49]
  FROM dbo.Table_1 x
  GROUP BY x.col2


 Result: 
 col2   48  49
 H0000   5  55
 H0100   6  66
 H0200   7  77
 H0300   8  88
 H0400   9  99
 H0500   10 100
```